# IEDriver, c#, modify delay between characters in sendKeys

Tags: c#, webdriver, sendkeys

When IEDriver is writing a text in a field, it does it character by character. It is the same with Chrome, but Firefox send all the characters at the same time. The IE and Chrome approach is slower.

Not only that, sometimes IE and Chromedriver dont send all the characters. And if the textfield they interact has an autocomplete, the autocomplete may interrupt the flow of characters and miss a character.

Is it possible to modify the delay between characters in IEdriver (actually, put it to zero)? Not chrome, iedriver. I am using iedriver 32bits, and I dont care about the philosophy of "char by char makes like more senz, lol".

Answer (score 0):

You can write a JS wrapper for typing in the text fields

```
IWebDriver driver;
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript(string.Format("document.getElementById("{0}").value={1};", yourLocatorStr, yourText));
```

This should be the fastest approach. Also, you can use different profiles when executing tests where the auto-complete is turned off.

Comment: In complicated text fields (like lookups in Dojo) this approach does not work.